# Flatten transparency in illustrator (not PDF file) is showing white lines/gap between the shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, transparency

I have an illustration with transparency's blending mode applied, I am willing to flatten the transparency for better output but when I apply Flatten Transparency some tiny white lines appear as outline around the shapes. Refer the image below:[image]

Comment: It is called a conflation artefact, a bug, that affects nearly all commercial and noncommercial vector rendering engines. (or in fact all practically used non research rendering engines mainly behaussa  most developpers have copied a idea. It will go away once the rendering engines get ported to harware accelarated rendering)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this many times in pdf's that have been flattened for printing. If you keep zooming in on the pdf and the white line stays the same thickness then it's probably not going to be an issue. It's just where the transparency has been flattened to create different coloured sections for output to printing plates. Contact your printer and get the pdf profiles that they use if you're unsure. If you change the compatibility in the pdf when you export from the native program to any version above Acrobat 4 you won't have this problem as only Acrobat 4 pdf's will be flattened.

Answer (score -4):

Well I guess it's may be your computer having low graphics. If you think it's not with graphic, then try to **restart** your illustrator software and try again.

Comment: What do you mean by "low graphics"? I'm sorry and I realize English isn't everyone's first language, but even if the English in this made sense, the answer itself does not, nor does it even answer the question presented in the first place.

Comment: @Manly What I meant with _graphic_ here is the **Graphic Resolution** of the computer.